# how to merge the codes of generate random ID into data files?

Tags: katalon-studio

How to merge the codes of generate random ID into data files?

I have done the codes to generate random ItemID (append timestamp)

And I had test case which get the excel stored at data file. The first column of data file is ItemID.

How do I merge the random ItemID codes into the existing data file codes?

So that I do not need to keep updating the excel file, new testID will be used at new test execution.

**codes for random ID**

```html
 @Keyword
 String getUniqueName() {
  String prodName = ('ItemID'+Integer.toString(getRandomNumber(1, 99))) + timeStamp()

  return prodName
 }
```

**codes for upload file**

```html
def requestObject = builder.withRestRequestMethod('POST')
.withRestUrl('http://'+GlobalVariable.URL+":"+GlobalVariable.Port + '/api/items/upload')
.withHttpHeaders([
  new TestObjectProperty('Content-Type', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'multipart/form-data')])
.withMultipartFormDataBodyContent([
 new FormDataBodyParameter('uploadedFile',"Data Files/ImportData.xlsx" , 'File'), ])
.build()
def response = WS.sendRequest(requestObject)
WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(response, 201)
```